# Dynamically change Portrait / Landscape orientation of crystal report in c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, landscape-portrait

How can I change the orientation of the crystal report in c# to Landscape orientation? I am using the crystal report in the portrait orientation.

Answer (score 16):

You may check this

> Right click--->Design--->Page SetUp--->Orientation--->LandScape format.

Answer (score 6):

Crystal Reports uses your current printer settings. Change those, and your report changes to match.

So, to change the orientation of your report to landscape view:

1. File -> Printer Setup.
2. In the "Orientation" section, choose "Landscape".

Answer (score 2):

In order to change the orientation to Landscape mode you need to go to Crystal Reports-> Design-> Printer Setup

Then change the orientation to Landscape or Portrait according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

For changing Orientation Of crystal report dynamically Follow following step:

```
 1. Copy Crystal Report and past in same project,Rename it.

 2. Now Right click on New Crystal Report > Design>Page SetUp > Orientation > LandScape ,that is set new new crystal report Orientation  as LandScape
 3. Last step is to Load new crystal report to ReportDocument at runtime
```

it will display crystal report in LandScape mode.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it at runtime, this will help you:

```
reportDocument1.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Landscape;
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument1;
```

I hope this will help you.